# What happens to a bounty if an answer is accepted during the grace period?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer, expired-bounty

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39276401/3628232) that had a bounty. It wasn't accepted by the OP until just after (< 1 hr) the bounty period expired and had entered the 24 hr "grace period".

Assuming the OP doesn't manually award the bounty, will I receive all or half of the bounty? The answer is currently the highest upvoted and has more than the 2 upvotes required.

Comment: As far as I know, you should get the full bounty when grace period is over. If you won't get it, update this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the bounty has just been awarded (in full), a few hours after the grace period ended. Looking at the bounty awarded indicator (as suggested by the comments below), it was awarded automatically.

Comment: Two ways to tell: Hover over the "bounty awarded" indicator on your answer. If it says "Community" (and it does) the awarding was automatic. Likewise, you can check the revision history of the question and also see there that "Community" awarded the bounty. If it had been manual, the user who posted the bounty would be listed in both places rather than "Community".

Comment: @Kendra That, or just look at the amount.  It's halved if it's automatically awarded.

Comment: @Servy It was not halved in this case, and was automatically awarded. The OP of the original question posted the bounty, and accepted the answer in the grace period. They did not manually award the bounty, but it was automatically awarded to the accepted answer for the full amount.